# Spring Boot JSON Many to one

Tags: angularjs, json, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I have problem with my code...

I create my single page application with Spring Boot and Angularjs.

Here is my users class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "admins")
public class Admin {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer adminid;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private String login;
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "groupid")
    private Group groupid;
    private Boolean active;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modifydate;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdate;

    public Admin() {
    }
   //setters ang getters
  }
```

And my secend entity class looks

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer groupid;
private String groupname;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date modifydate;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdate;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "groupid")
@JsonIgnore
private List<Admin> groupusers;

public Group() {
}

public Group(Integer groupid) {
    this.groupid = groupid;
}
}
```

My frontend application send request to the server, like this

```
   {adminid: null, name: "dsa", surname: "dsa", email: "d", login: "sada", groupid: "1", active: true}
```

I have problem with groupid property when i try add new admin...

```
 WARN 27742 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of com.patryk.model.Group: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1')
  at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@9fe378; line: 1, column: 83] (through reference chain: com.patryk.model.Admin["groupid"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.patryk.model.Group: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1')
  at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@9fe378; line: 1, column: 83] (through reference chain: com.patryk.model.Admin["groupid"])
```

My controller:

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/api/admins")
 public class AdminController {

@Autowired
private AdminService adminService;


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> addUser(@RequestBody Admin admin)
{
    adminService.save(admin);
    return new ResponseEntity<Admin> (admin,HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

How can I find a solution? Anyone know what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct the object from the `groupid`.

```
{
   adminid: null, 
   name: "dsa", 
   surname: "dsa", 
   email: "d", 
   login: "sada", 
   groupid: { "groupid": "1"}, 
   active: true
}
```

If you want to retain your original json that isn't working, you'll need to create a custom Deserializer so that you can convert `"groupid": "1"` into the `Group` entity.